# any known gdb cosmetic bug that may display function parameter value incorrectly?

Tags: gdb, stack

Is it known that GNU gdb 7.6 has a cosmetic bug which may show incorrect or random values for optimized variables or function arguments?

Take the backtrace below for example. The function allocb() in frame #11 calls allocb_internal() with the 3rd argument set to its dsize value (i.e., 793) plus 20 (i.e., sum = 793 + 20). Is there an known gdb bug which may show a value of 11551 in frame #10 instead of 813 or ?

```
#9  prepare_tp_header (reliable=0, length=11551, bp=0x7f678abd96c0, receiver_id=4 '\004') at foo.c:690
#10 allocb_internal (attempt_reserve_bp=0, reliable=0, dsize=11551, receiver_id=4 '\004') at foo.c:1737
#11 allocb (receiver_id=receiver_id@entry=4 '\004', dsize=dsize@entry=793, tos=tos@entry=9) at foo.c:1748
```

I expected gdb to show dsize in frame #11 as 813 or .

Comment: GDB 7.6 is ~10 years old!  Many bugs and improvements have been fixed since then.  I'd suggest trying GDB 14 and see if it gives better results.  That said, the problem could easily be poor debug information from the compiler.  If the compiler says that a particular variable can be found in a particular register then GDB is going to believe it, if instead, that register has been reused, you'll see incorrect values like this.  If your compiler is as old as your debugger, then this might not be helping!

Comment: my compiler is gcc 4.8.5. hard to imagine the toolchain has this cheap joke which makes nothing of gdb trustable.

Comment: That compiler is 9 years old.  Any bugs in this area might have been fixed.  Maybe you could see if there are more recent tools available for your distribution?

Comment: The tools are managed by 3rd party and not under my control, so... Thanks for feedback anyway!